# UITableview button image disappear while scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uibutton

I am having an UITableview in that in that having three buttons, and the buttons having conditions them working well. My problem **is when I select any button image change to the selected image. but when I scroll the table view selected image are changed to normal image. I want to save the selected in the table view**. I have seen many stack overflow, but its not helping me. any one help me please.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
CustomizedCellView *cell = (CustomizedCellView *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

cell = [table dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[CustomizedCellView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}


button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button1.frame = CGRectMake(80, 27, 36, 36);
    [button1 setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"l"ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lblue.png"]
             forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(radiobtn4:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    button1.tag=1;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:button1];
button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button2.frame = CGRectMake(160, 27, 36, 36);
    [button2 setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"e"ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"eblue.png"]
             forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    [button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(radiobtn4:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:button2];
    button2.tag=3;


    button3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button3.frame = CGRectMake(240, 27, 36, 36);
    [button3 setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"v"ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"vblue.png"]
             forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    [button3 addTarget:self action:@selector(radiobtn4:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:button3];
    button3.tag=2;

- (void)radiobtn4:(UIButton *)sender

{
    UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell *)sender.superview;
    if(sender.selected == NO)
    {

        if(sender.tag==1){

            UIButton *otherButton=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
            otherButton.selected=YES;
            UIButton *other=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
            other.selected=NO;

        }else if(sender.tag==2){
            UIButton *otherButton=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
            otherButton.selected=YES;
            UIButton *other=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
            other.selected=NO;


        } else if(sender.tag == 3)
        {
            UIButton *otherButton=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
            otherButton.selected=YES;

        }

    } else  if(sender.selected == YES)

    {
        if(sender.tag==1){
            UIButton *otherButton=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
            [otherButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"l.png"]
                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            otherButton.selected=NO;


        }else if(sender.tag==2){
            UIButton *otherButton=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
            [otherButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"v.png"]
                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            otherButton.selected=NO;

        }  else if(sender.tag == 3)
        {
            UIButton *otherButton=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
            [otherButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"e.png"]
                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            otherButton.selected=NO;

        }

    }

}
```

above is my coding, i want to use any array to store the selected image,how can i do that process, please help me in coding.

Comment: this is because iOS deque cells that are not visible in screen, and in your `cellForRowIndexPath` method you are recreating default cell without making any check that if the cell was selected or not

Comment: @SyedAliSalman please explain me in coding

Comment: you need to change you logic a little

Comment: @SyedAliSalman can u edit my code, please

Comment: the code is wrong. NSString *CellIdentifier  - should be a static value. you should  addSubviews inside if (cell == nil) {} block and subviews must be created with tag so you access it by ViewByTag on outside of if block.  OR add subviews on CustomizedCellView so you can access button by CustomizedCellView.button1